# How to get the correct frame size of UICollectionView within UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

## Goal

I'm trying to clone the following newsfeed layout in iOS 15:

[image]

## My Implementation

`PostCell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and `ImageGridCollectionView` is a subclass of `ContentSizeFitCollectionView` (which enables dynamic height).

```swift
class ContentSizeFitCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

`ImageGridCollectionView` is implemented with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, the delegate method of which looks like:

```swift
extension ImageGridCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    private func getItemSize(width: FractionalLength, height: FractionalLength) -> CGSize {
        let screenWidth = self.frame.size.width
        let itemWidth: CGFloat = (screenWidth - spacing * (1 / width.fractionalValue - 1)) * width.fractionalValue
        let itemHeight: CGFloat = screenWidth * height.fractionalValue
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let item = indexPath.item
        switch numberOfImages {
        case 1:
            return getItemSize(width: .one, height: .threeFourths)
        case 2:
            return getItemSize(width: .oneHalf, height: .threeFourths)
        case 3:
            if item < 1 {
                return getItemSize(width: .one, height: .oneHalf)
            } else {
                return getItemSize(width: .oneHalf, height: .oneHalf)
            }
        case 4:
            return getItemSize(width: .oneHalf, height: .oneHalf)
        default:
            if item < 2 {
                return getItemSize(width: .oneHalf, height: .oneHalf)
            } else {
                return getItemSize(width: .oneThird, height: .oneThird)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `PostCell`, the auto layout for the `ImageGridCollectionView` is implemented:

```swift
contentView.addSubview(imageGridCollectionView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageGridCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textContentLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: .standardTopMargin),
            imageGridCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            imageGridCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            statHorizontalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageGridCollectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: .standardTopMargin),
            ...
        ])
```

## Problem

The problem of the implementation above is that while calculating the collectionView's flow layout, the collectionView is accessing `self.frame` in `getItemSize(width:height:)`, which is `(-32783.0, 0.0, 65566.0, 0.0)` at the time it is accessed.

As a result, the `itemHeight` is calculated based on the enormous `screenWidth`(`65566.0`).

## Solutions I tried

Wrapping `imageGridCollectionView` with `UIStackView` kinda worked (not perfect though; the height occasionally becomes zero):

```swift
let stack = UIStackView()
stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stack.addArrangedSubview(imageGridCollectionView)
contentView.addSubview(stack)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textContentLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: .standardTopMargin),
      stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
      stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
])
```

But I want a cleaner solution instead of this workaround, or at least understand why it does work.

I'm wondering if there's something like `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in TableViewCells so that I can easily access *updated* frame size.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: this may help https://github.com/rubygarage/collection-view-layouts

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. `layoutIfNeeded` was the key.

In `PostCell`,

```swift
    func configureCell(with post: Post) {
        commentCountLabel.text = "\(post.comments.withCommas(unit: "개"))"
        likeCountLabel.text = post.likes.withCommas(unit: "개")
        textContentLabel.text = post.content
        self.layoutIfNeeded()  // important
    }
```

This fixed everything.